# High temperature (~20°C above baseline) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, temperature

Until yesterday my computer had temperatures around 40°-43°. Today my PC without me starting any program has temperatures around 58°-62°. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and translate it to English. For the temperature problem, you may look at the processes using too much CPU (using `top`).

Comment: Thanks, but in the end I updated the BIOS and went back to its usual temperatures.

Answer (score 2):

After updating the BIOS Ubuntu 18.04 went back to its usual temperatures.